# TS compiler not happy about union type involving enum brand (nominal typing)

Tags: typescript, types, union-types

I am using an enum to achieve nominal typing (like e.g. suggested in the [TypeScript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/tips/nominalTyping.html) book):

```
enum ExampleIdBrand {}
export type ExampleId = ExampleIdBrand & string
const exampleId: ExampleId = '42' as ExampleId

const m1 = (e: ExampleId) => e.toUpperCase()
m1(exampleId) // ✅
```

So far, everything works just like expected. However, if I change the method to accept a (wider) union type, the compiler no longer accepts my `exampleId`:

```
const m2 = (e: ExampleId | 'whatever') => e.toUpperCase()
m2('whatever') // ✅
m2(exampleId) //  Does not compile
```

Why doesn't the last line compile just fine? (TS 3.3.4000)

Comment: Hi Rahel, do you use a special dialect? .toUpperCase() is a function, it requires braces.

Comment: No special dialect, just me being sloppy – will fix it, tx!

Comment: @DanielDietrich it will work like that as well.. it just does something different ..

Comment: Yes, I've fiddled around a bit. The cast in `const exampleId: ExampleId = '42' as ExampleId;` is already a smell. If we remove the cast and make ExampleId a string `export type ExampleId = string;`, it works. It seems that it is not possible to create ~~union~~ intersection types with enums. Will google a bit...

Comment: Well, but then we lose the nominal typing (https://netzwerg.ch/blog/2018/11/21/react-redux-typescript/#5)

Answer (score 1):

In TypeScript, enums can be of type number or string. A number has no .toUpperCase() method.

Your example should work because the enum is narrowed to be of type string.

A workaround would be:

```js
enum ExampleIdBrand {}
export type ExampleId = ExampleIdBrand;
const exampleId: ExampleId = '42';

const m1 = (e: ExampleId) => e.toString().toUpperCase();
m1(exampleId);

const m2 = (e: ExampleId | 'whatever') => e.toString().toUpperCase();
m2('whatever'); // ✅
m2(exampleId); // ✅
```

Comment: However, you are right, Rahel.  Following "TypeScript Deep Dive", I would also expect that the `ExampleId & string` narrows the enum to be of type string. Your example should compile but it does not. Maybe a compiler bug? In my example above, the union isn't needed at all. I will edit the post...

Comment: This is not what the user is attempting to do, they want to create a type, that while a string at runtime is not compatible with any other string at compiler time, atleast not without a type assertion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557714/make-two-types-different-by-parameter/49557889#49557889

Comment: That certainly sounds like a good workaround, thanks @DanielDietrich. But just like you, I still don't understand why my initial example does not compile 

Answer (score 1):

What happens to an intersection that is an empty set (ie there are no  values that can be instances of the intersection) is  is something that has changed. I can't really find the docs, although I will keep looking, but in certain conditions such intersections will collapse to never. And we see this at work in this case, `ExampleId | 'whatever' = never |  'whatever' =  'whatever'`

```
const m2 = (e: ExampleId | 'whatever') => e.toUpperCase()
type x =  Parameters<typeof m2>[0] //  'whatever'
```

To keep the nominal nature of `ExampleId` we can  add a property instead:

```
enum ExampleIdBrand {}
export type ExampleId = { __brand: ExampleIdBrand } & string
const exampleId: ExampleId = '42' as ExampleId

const m1 = (e: ExampleId | "whatever") => e.toUpperCase()
m1(exampleId) // ✅
m1("whatever")// ✅
```

Or if we want to hide that member really well we can use an intersection with a class with a private field:

```
enum ExampleIdBrand { }
class Brand<T> { private __brand: T}
export type ExampleId = Brand<ExampleIdBrand> & string
const exampleId: ExampleId = '42' as ExampleId

const m1 = (e: ExampleId | "whatever") => e.toUpperCase()
m1(exampleId) // ✅
m1("whatever")// ✅
```

Or drop the enum and use this `class ExampleIdBrand { private __brand!: any}`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions. "What happens to an intersection that is not really creatable" – would you mind elaborating why this intersection is "not creatable"?

Comment: @RahelLüthy clarified a bit, using set language. I think these are the relevand PRs: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20001, https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/23751

Comment: Wow, PR 23751 seems to explain it: "10 | number is reduced to just 10" – this is SO not how I would expect it to work  Are you aware of this, @DanielDietrich?

Comment: @RahelLüthy that is a typo, `10 | number` is `number`. `10 & number` is `10`

Comment: That would certainly make more sense!