# How to handle TypeScript custom DataTypes and maintain type safety

Tags: typescript, types

I am TypeScript begineer and I have this problem: I have interface and type for `Room`:

```
export interface IRoom {
  name: string;
}

export type RoomId = number;
```

then I want to define function like so:

```
export function test(roomId: RoomId, room: IRoom) {
  return 'FOOBAR';
}
```

and then I want to call this function. But I am still getting function parameters `test(number, IRoom)`, but not `test(RoomId, IRoom)`.
This means that I will later forget what type of value need to go into this function without looking into source of this function.

Onlz two options I see are:

- `test(<FloorId>123, <IRoom>{ name: 'foobar' });`
- `test(123, { name: 'foobar' })`

Is there any other way?
Maybe more type safe way?

Last possible way I see is to make everything `class` which seems as too much logic and performance overhead:

```
export class RoomId {
  id: number;
  constructor(id: number) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}

export class Room implements IRoom {
  name: string;
  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

// Calling `test()`
addRoom(new FloorId(1), new Room('foobar'));
```

Comment: I think this answers your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557714/make-two-types-different-by-parameter

Comment: I believe you're looking for opaque types. This is unfortunately not a TS feature at the moment. There's a github issue for it here with a workaround: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/15807