# Typescript structural typing

Tags: typescript, structural-typing

I know typescript uses structural typing system, however is there a way to make typescript return error on assignment of those two type?

```
interface user {
 name: string
}
interface user2 {
  name: string,
  numberOrNull: number | null
}

let usr: user = {
  name: "hey"
}

let usr2: user2 = {
  name: "as",
  numberOrNull: 12
}

usr = usr2 // no typescript error
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware, branding is the only way to do this. See [this question's answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557714/make-two-types-different-by-parameter). That question is about making two different flavors of string incompatible, but branding (the answer) applies to your example as well.

Comment: I think [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49557714/make-two-types-different-by-parameter) answer the above, but I didn't want to close the question on my own (dupehammer). I'd like to see if others agree first.

Comment: Yes, I tought about Discriminated Union. Just wondered if there is a more elegant solution, but guess not. Getting tired of typescript already. Thank you, still!

Comment: What actual problem this example has as a background? Or none?

Comment: I am using prisma ORM and need to get the returned type (which is dependent on the selected fields). It created this weakness in the code that you might  include the password for example and forget to remove it. I though that by creating a type (used for storing info into the session without any password field) I am going to be able to include only the fields that are specified and not anything else. Unfortunately It doesn't work that way. Moreover I am bound to some prisma utility types and functions that use prisma auto generated types. Not sure what is the way to fix the weakness elegantly.

Comment: Okey, let me paraphrase the question. Is there a way to make all object keys that are not defined to type never ?

something like: 

interface user {
 name: string,
 [anything else]: never
}